# Appending lines as comma seperated values in bash

Tags: bash, shell

Using a combination of commands, I extract out the following line from a text file (say file1.txt) and store it in another file, say opfile.txt

**opfile.txt**

```
1%
12 of 1G
200 of 2G
```

Now, say file1 values get updated and the next time I run my command, I get the values

```
2%
10 of 1G
100 of 1G
```

Now, I want the output to be appended as comma separated values on each line of my opfile.txt like so.

**opfile.txt**

```
1%,2%
12 of 1G,10 of 1G
200 of 2G,100 of 1G
```

How exactly do I append it?

To get the first output into opfile.txt, I use the command

```
 grep "#0" TestOutput | cut -f 4,5,6 | tr '\t' "\n " > opfile.txt
```

And that what inputs the data into opfile.txt initially.

Now, to get the second bunch of data, I use this command

```
grep "#0" TestOutput | cut -f 4,5,6 | awk '{print ","$1}{print ","$2" "$3" "$4}{print ","$5" "$6" "$7}'
```

And that gives me the following

```
,7.1%
,230.9M of 1G
,700.3M of 2G
```

Simply using the >> to append it into opfile.txt is giving me the output on all different lines.

How do I get them on the same line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `paste` command for this:

```
paste -d, opfile.txt <(your_command)

1%,2%
12 of 1G,10 of 1G
200 of 2G,100 of 1G
```

Where `your_command` is your command producing second output.